# Where is the output of pdftoppm?

Tags: pdf, conversion

Hi I followed the instructions for using `pdftoppm` in the terminal so as to convert a pdf to an image.

I tried:

```
pdftoppm -png file.pdf prefix
```

I also tried it with the resolution parameters `rx` etc.... and also as it was the only pdf in the directory I read further down in the thread that you don't even have to put the name. So tried all of this and just kept getting poppler returning all the options and parameter choices as if I typed `pdftoppm --help` which of course i hadn't. What is going on?

All I want to do is convert a bloody image so i can insert it into a cell in an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

`pdftoppm` creates output files in the directory where You run it. So if You simply open a terminal, You always start at Your home directory. This:

```
user@pc:~$ pdftoppm -png file.pdf prefix
```

should create png file(s) in home directory (`~` is the same as `/home/user`) with name(s) starting with `prefix`.

I've just checked it on my machine (Xubuntu 15.04) - it works like a charm.

Comment: Can we able to specify the output folder in command line?

Comment: @PankajBadukale Just change `prefix` to full path to destination folder.